# .htaccess redirect or PHP change

Tags: php, class, function, .htaccess

The main navigation of my site is coded like this:

```
<li><a href="index.php?pageID='.$key.'">'.$value.'</a></li>'."\n";
```

But I would like the URL of the links to look like `domain.co.nz/pagename`, not `domain.co.nz/index.php?pageId=pagename`

How would you recommend I accomplish this?

Comment: if you want it to show 'xyz', then type 'xyz'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?pageID=$1
```

First line turns on mod_rewrite. Second line sets the base URL to / (it's annoying, but you have to set it to the base path you're dealing with). Third and fourth lines make sure the request doesn't exist as a file, or as a directory. And the last line is the actual magic; basically it searches for "anything", captures what it finds in $1, and "rewrites" the URL to index.php?pageID=$1. If you learn to use regexes, you can do much more complicated things as well.

Comment: Does it just not do anything? Or what happens?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can accomplish this with a .htaccess RewriteRule. In your .htaccess file, include:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule (.*) index.php?pageId=$1
```

This means:

If the `REQUEST_FILENAME` is not a valid file, redirect *the entire URL* to `index.php?pageId=`*the entire URL*

You'd then change your navigation to:

```
echo "<li><a href="/'.$key.'">'.$value.'</a></li>'."\n";
```

**Edit:** I moved Trivikrtam's edit inline, see above. The RewriteRule should be `index.php?pageId=$1` not `/index.php?pageId=$1`. Thanks @Trivikrtam!

Comment: Hi,I have done that and now it shows main domain/number and not maindomain/subfolder/number

Comment: It's showing maindomain/number because redirection is being done to root folder.

You must change second line in code, so that redirection occurs in subfolder, as follows:

RewriteRule (.*) index.php?pageId=$1